# Laptop does not resume from suspend in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend

I run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 5577. I recently got the battery replaced, and after the battery swap, my system is failing to resume after being suspended. On waking up the system, a black screen with a static cursor is displayed, and the system does not respond to any keyboard or mouse input. This forces me to restart the system to use it.

Interestingly, if I resume from suspend within a few minutes of suspending, everything works fine. If I suspend for anything more than 5 minutes, it hangs when resuming. Also, this was not issue before swapping battery.

I have tried downgrading and upgrading my Nvida drivers as well, but nothing seems to work. My system is dual-booted with Windows 10.

System Configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.11.0-41-generic 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile\Intel HD Graphics 630

Comment: Considering *this was not issue before swapping battery* you have to suspect the new battery first and foremost. Is it genuine Dell or 3rd party "compatible". I suspect the latter and if confirmed, there's your answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto That was my first concern as well, but the battery is genuine dell and not a compatible one.

Comment: Didi you also change the button cell that powers the Real Time Clock? Your fuzzy description sounds like RTC battery.